# How can I prevent $window.location.href from stopping ongoing requests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

In my angularjs (angularjs 1.3) app there is a place where the user can download a pdf file.
This is done in a controller using:

```
$window.location.href = 'pdf/123456';
```

which saves the file on the users computer. The url in the broswer is never really changed, the user is still on the same page in the angular app.

When I set the locations this way however, ongoing requests get cancelled when using Firefox. Using Chrome there is no problem. The only solution I've come up with is to wait with other requests until the pdf is downloaded but since that can take some time I would like to start them before the download is complete.

Is there any way of fixing this? Can I download the file in any other way? I don't want to open a popup window.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to download a file is to create an `<a>` tag with the file as target and simulate a click on it. Like this:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'pdf/123456';
a.download = 'document_name';
a.target = '_blank';
a.click();
```

Comment: Thanks @yadejo but this will not work in my case. The download should happen automatically after a promise has been resolved.

Comment: You can't execute this code when the promise resolves?

Comment: I can, but other ongoing requests get cancelled when I call $window.location.href = ...